# Overriding method throws checked exception not defined in interface

Tags: java, interface

Say I have an interface `DataStore` which has the method `public List<Entity> getEntities()`. The class `SqlDataStore` implements this interface. The thing is that when calling `SqlDataStore.getEntities()` an `SQLException`could be thrown. I cannot alter the interface to add this checked exception to the method signature, because you could also write an implementation `XmlDataStore` which is accessing XML files to fetch the data. What should I do to handle those checked exceptions the implementations could throw?

Comment: Wrap them in unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, or better still, wrap them in whatever type of exception your interface _will_ let you throw.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can alter the interface to add the checked exception to the method signature. The method in `XmlDataStore` doesn't have to declare that it throws the exception.

Comment: @pbabcdefp That way I would have to add every exception type the implementations could possibly throw. Is that a common solution?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do you mean defining my own exception type, say `DataStoreException` which contains a reference to the thrown exception and add this one to the interface methods?

Comment: You could do that, if `DataStoreException` is a checked exception. You don't have to declare unchecked exceptions with a `throws` clause.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Okay so I would have to define a class that extends RuntimeException. I read though that only exceptions that you can prevent programmatically are RuntimeExceptions in Java. That would not be the case if the source of the exception would be a problem connecting to the database in the case of the `SqlDataStore` class. Would extending RuntimeException still be valid to simplify things?

Comment: @urbaindepuce I suggest looking at how Spring Data handles this (the docs for Spring Data Commons should explain).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what I did in lack of better ideas. I defined a class `DataStoreException` that extended `RuntimeException`. I removed the throws clause from the interface definition. When a checked exception is thrown in one of the classes that implemented `DataStore` I just catch it and wrap it in `DataStoreException` and rethrow it.